# No need to save draft in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mfmailcomposer

After clicking the cancel button of MFMailComposeViewController action sheet of save draft or not is generated. 
[image]

I dont want this action sheet how can i achieve that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, this does nothing in Simulator, draft will be saved in mail application. Refer the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3939905/876283

Comment: I think you may not be able to change it as `MFMailComposeViewController` is a framework and you may not play with it.. Also chances of app getting rejected are quite as Apple is not gonna like it..

Comment: @iNoob : you misinterpreted the question I suppose.. :-)

Comment: @anonymous, not entirely :D, the answer i linked had the line "It is not possible to alter the options available in this action sheet, as it is entirely controlled by the mail compose view controller." Hope OP gets it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

> **Important The mail composition interface itself is not customizable
>   and must not be modified by your application.** In addition, after
>   presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make
>   further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the
>   content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored.
>   Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the
>   interface.

First line answers your question I think.

Comment: Good answer.. Thanks you gave evidence to my comment.. +1