# Possible to "Save Draft" Programmatically in MFMailCompseViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I know that the documentation for `MFMailComposeViewController` specifically says you cannot send programmatically, but is the same true for "Save Draft"?  I have a situation where I will need to dismiss the mail composer programmatically, and it would be great if I could save the users email as a draft instead of losing it.

Tried looking in the apple docs and I do not believe there were any methods to call to accomplish this in `MFMailComposeViewController`. Would like to post the question here before I determine that this is definitely not possible.

Comment: From the post linked, it sounds like Apple allows little/no interaction with the mail composer after it has been presented to the user, and I'm also not seeing anything to save programmatically. My educated guess is that it's not possible, but I won't 100% rule it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810627/no-need-to-save-draft-in-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: Stonz2, Right that is where I am at. Seems very likely that this is not possible though, and I will assume so unless proven otherwise.